# MySQL select * from the date of today

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-workbench

I'm running a simple code that checks ping and takes the IP address from SQL.

I want the code to run only for those I didn't see today, so every run it will remove from the list the IP addresses he already get answer, but the MySQL command is not working for me.

This is the command I have found:

```
select
IP
From 
database.devices
where DATE(LastConnected) != Date((now))
```

The data that I save in the data base is using this format:

```
25-may-18 14:30:21
dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss
```

What is wrong? Maybe I need to take only the date? 25.5.18? If so - how can I do this?

Comment: Hi! Saying your code is not running is not enough, tell us the error =)

Comment: Use `DATE_FORMAT` to specify your format before use date functions on it.

Comment: is does nothing .... :-) I run the command and see noting

Comment: "*using this format*" makes it sound like we are storing datetime values as string type (e.g. `VARCHAR`) rather than using MySQL `DATETIME` datatype which is purposefully designed to store datetime values. (But maybe I'm reading more into the "using this format" and dd-Monthname-two_digit_year than is warranted.)

Comment: @spencer7593 - true , I'm saving the data as string , so what to do? how to fix ? and if I cahnge it in the datatype on the table - what will happnd to the data? will I need to reenter it ? or it will change it alone?   Thanks ,

Comment: when I try to compare it to a string - Its working  - so I guess this is the problem , but now how can I fix this (If I will hav eto - I can delete the data from LastConnected and start over - but only if there is no other option )

Answer (score 0):

```
You make a mistake in **Date((now))** instead of **Date(now())** 

Try this:Given all record instead of today
select IP From database.devices where DATE(LastConnected) != Date(now())

Given all record of today
select IP From database.devices where DATE(LastConnected) = Date(now())
```

Comment: I have both options before I ask - both of them return nothing . I think maybe the problem is lilke @spencer said , the decleration of the data as Date an not string ...

Comment: I try same in my local. its working find using typecasting **DATETIME** and also **VARCHAR**. and i get the result. Find the record.

Comment: how do you write the date ? like I did ?   "25-may-18 16:20:00"

Comment: your date should be in **Y-m-d H:i:s** format. Otherwise **DATE()** function is not working

Comment: the  "problem" is - that is how the device show the date+time and I gust read it , can't change it. if I cahnge the varchar to DATE - will it give me errors?

Comment: Try this:
select * from (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(LastConnected, "%Y-%m-%d") as dd FROM database.devices) as a WHERE dd != now()

Comment: @ hitesh makodiya - nothing , give en ampty colomn name dd

Answer (score 0):

"*using this format*" makes it sound like we are storing datetime values as string type (e.g. `VARCHAR`) rather than using MySQL `DATETIME` datatype which is purposefully designed to store datetime values. (But maybe I'm reading more into the "*using this format*" and the bizarre dd-Monthname-two_digit_year than is warranted.)

---

If we want to use MySQL date/datetime operations, we can convert the string values into an actual `DATETIME` dataype using the `STR_TO_DATE` function.

And we can test expressions in the select list, so we can see what is actually happening...

```
SELECT d.lastconnected
     , STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T') AS lc_datetime_
     , DATE(NOW())
     , DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
FROM database.devices
```

Once we have expressions tested, we can use them in the WHERE clause

To return the rows that have a lastconnected string that represents a datetime that is "in" the current day, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT d.lastconnected
     , STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T') AS lc_datetime_
     , ... 
  FROM database.devices d
 WHERE STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T') >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   AND STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T')  < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

If `dt_lastconnected` was a `DATETIME` column, our query could use an efficient range scan operation on an index that has `dt_lastconnected` as the leading column:

```
SELECT ... 
  FROM database.devices d
 WHERE d.dt_lastconnected  >= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 0 DAY
   AND d.dt_lastconnected   < DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

---

*Q: If I change ... the datatype* [of lastconnected column] *on the table - what will happen to the data? Will I need to reenter it ? Or it will change it alone?*

To avoid "wiping out" the contents of the lastconnected column, we can add another column of the appropriate type, and set the value from the existing column.

If the table is a reasonably sized set of rows, we could do

```
ALTER TABLE database.device ADD dt_lastconnected DATETIME
;

UPDATE database.device
   SET dt_lastconnected = STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T')
;
```

That will convert whatever values that it can. Rows with `lastconnected` values that can't be parsed into a valid datetime will have `dt_lastconnected` set to NULL.

If we want to populate the new column on our INSERT statements, we will need to provide values in the proper format, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS` e.g.

```
INSERT INTO databases.device ( ... , dt_lastconnected , ... ) VALUES
  ( ... , '2018-05-25 18:35:15' , ... )
, ( ... , STR_TO_DATE('25-May-2018 18:35:15','%d-%b-%y %T') , ... )
, ( ... , NOW() , ... )
```

Once we have the INSERT code corrected, we could drop the string column, and rename the new column. (This will be more involved if `lastconnected` is a column in an index.)

```
-- remove old column
ALTER TABLE databases.devices
  DROP lastconnected ;

-- rename column
ALTER TABLE databases.devices
  CHANGE dt_lastconnected lastconnected DATETIME ;
```

Comment: Do I need to change the varchar to Date in the table setting ?

Comment: I have run the first part - and it didn't print nothing

Comment: @Korenron: It's not mandatory to change the datatype of the column, but having the column defined as the proper type is going to be more efficient and more convenient.  If the first query in my answer doesn't return any rows, then either there are no rows in the table, or there's some kind of error happening. (The first query doesn't include a WHERE clause, so we can get rows back, and "see" the result of the expressions.  With the STR_TO_DATE function, we need to tell MySQL the format of the string we're passing in. The formats are documented in the MySQL Reference Manual.)

Comment: Ok - I see it's going to be a problem :) , so let start from the start...   the format I'm getting into the sql can't be change(this is how  I get it from the device) .  now if I add a new row as data type=Date and not varcahr45 , then will I be able to use the date compare sql function?

Comment: @Korenron: We can use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to convert a string to `DATETIME`.  We can do the conversion in an INSERT statement... we can convert it into a DATETIME and store into a DATETIME column. (This is the normative pattern). With that, we can gain data validation, efficiency and the convenience of MySQL builtin handling for DATETIME.

Comment: @Korenron: We can store datetime as character strings,... we can store whatever we want in a character string. But with character strings, we can't make use of any MySQL builtin DATE/DATETIME functionality. The "shim" is the MySQL `STR_TO_DATE` function, which does the conversion from character string into DATETIME dataype; we can operate on the result from STR_TO_DATE like we would operate on DATETIME. The disadvantages of this approach far outweigh any advantage we gain.

Comment: so lets do it .... i have created a new colomn name "NewLastOnline" now what datatype should I set it ? Date/Datetime/time/timestamp? remember my data format is 25-may-18 14:30:21

Comment: Use datatype `DATETIME`.

Comment: Ok - now what to do? I see all the lines are 0000-00-00 00:00:00 ,

Comment: Run an UPDATE statement to assign a value, derive the value from the character string, using the STR_TO_DATE function. (I gave an exmaple of that in my answer.)

Comment: I have run this   SELECT lastconnected
     , STR_TO_DATE(lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T') 
FROM database.devices    and now I can see that in the tmp colomn the correct time stamp of the sql - now where is the update? how to I copy it to the NewLastOnline

Comment: There's an example UPDATE statement in my answer, above.

Comment: something is not working ,   when I run this: select d.LastOnline
, str_to_date(d.LastOnline , '%d-%b-%y %T') AS lc_datetime_
,DATE(NOW())
,DATE(NOW()) + interval 1 day
from sample.table1 d
where str_to_date(LastOnline , '%d-%b-%y %T') >= DATE(NOW()) + interval 0 day
and str_to_date(LastOnline , '%d-%b-%y %T') < DATE(NOW()) + interval 1 day        -   I can see he print me 4 columns that lc_datetime is in the correct format - but I can't update the db , why ? I have try to use "UPDATE database.device
   SET dt_lastconnected = STR_TO_DATE(d.lastconnected,'%d-%b-%y %T')"  - not wroking